# How to configure PayPal Smart Payment Buttons for local pickup?

Tags: paypal

I want to use PayPal to pay at a restaurants website for local pickup or delivery. My code seems to work for delivery, but I could not figure out how to use local pickup.
The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-shipping_type) mentions a property called shipping_type which could be set to PICKUP, but it isn't clear where to set that property.

When I call actions.order.create with the following JSON object, PayPal still tells the user to choose a delivery address:

```
{
    shipping: {shipping_type: "PICKUP", type: "PICKUP"},
    shipping_type: "PICKUP",
    shipping_option: {type: "PICKUP"},
    "application_context": {
        "payment_method": { "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED" }
    },
    "purchase_units": [ {
        "shipping": { "option": { "type": "PICKUP" } },
        "shipping_option": { "type": "PICKUP" },
        "application_context": { "payment_method": { "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED" } },
        "items": [
            { "name": "XXL Hamburger", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": "11.50" }, "quantity": 1 },
            { "name": "XXL Rumpsteak", "unit_amount": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": "24.90" }, "quantity": 1 }
        ],
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "36.40",
            "breakdown": { "item_total": { "currency_code": "EUR", "value": "36.40" } }
        }
    } ]
}
```

Does anyone has a working example?

By the way: When testing my code, it is unclear if IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED does do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PayPal still tells the user to choose a delivery address

To have no shipping address as part of a PayPal transaction, [use](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context):

```
    application_context: {
        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
    }
```